# Why .class file of java needs to be executed on JVM?

Tags: jvm

As per my knowledge, JVM is a process virtual machine which means it does not emulate the entire existing computer architechture but emulates/mimics only the cpu of the host computer.

Now, my question is:
Why a .class java file needs to be executed inside virtual CPU(i.e. JVM) instead of being executed on actual CPU memory of the host computer?

Comment: Because the codes in a .class file are JVM instructions, not real machine instructions.

Answer (score 1):

For code to run on the actual CPU, it has to be in the instruction set of that CPU. Each CPU architecture has its own, distinct instruction set, so code written for one CPU won't run on another type of CPU.

The point of defining a Java Virtual Machine is so that the code will run on any type of computer, as long as it has a JVM interpreter.

Comment: "For code to run on the actual CPU, it has to be in the instruction set of that CPU."  -what do you mean by 'instruction set of CPU?' and what do you mean by 'a code should be in the instruction set of that CPU.' ?

Comment: If you don't understand that, maybe you need to learn how computes work. I'm not going to try to teach that here.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM instructions are not real CPU instructions but are for an abstract CPU.
Add to that some security proofs on the JVM byte code.
The JVM implementation's Just in Time compiler will translate abstract instructions to host CPU instructions on demand to achieve better performance.

Answer (score 1):

JVM actually conversts the java bytecode to the instruction set applicable to that particular CPU.Every CPU do not have similar instruction set.
So .class file is generated as it can run on any CPU. JVM does the task of converting onto machin code applicable to it.